# Difference between "sq km" and "km sq"

Tags: terminology, area, unit-of-measure

If I have a square with side $2\ \text{km}$, what is its area: $2\ \text{sq km}$ or $4\ \text{km}^2$?

Comment: The area is $4$ sq. km. or $4\text{ km}^2$. The units *square kilometer* and $\text{ km}^2$ mean the same thing.

Comment: How many 1kmx1km squares can you fit in it? Ergo?

Comment: Or you can say: open parenthesis two kilometer closed parenthesis squared: $(2~\mathrm{km})^2$. `:-)`

Comment: The notation $4\,\mathrm{km}^2$ will be understood all over the world. The notation $4\,\mathrm{sq. km}$ only in English speaking countries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A square with side $2\ \text{km}$ has area $4\ \text{km}^2$. This is pronounced as *four square kilometres*.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that a triangle has $\text{height = }a \text{ cm}, \text{ base = }b \text{ cm}$. The area, in mathematical notation, is $\Large {a\cdot b \over 2} \normalsize \text{cm}^2 $.

You may pronounce the above as *the quantity a times b all over two square centimeters*, **even though there is no difference at all.**

Comment: Your area formula is a factor of 10,000,000,000 off.

Comment: @Henning: Thanks, I just got it right.

Comment: But now the pronunciation is wrong.

Comment: Heh, you're a lifesaver.

Comment: @Hennig. What do you mean by your comment 10-billion off

Comment: @VAR121: The comment is no longer relevant to the answer that appears above, because it was already edited to correct the error.  It previously said km$^2$ where it should have said cm$^2$, and $1$km$^2=10^{10}$cm$^2$.

Answer (score -2):

Mathematical convention is that the word squared $(x^2)$ is a number multiplied by itself. Therefore $1\ {\rm km}$ squared is one square kilometers, but $2\ {\rm km}$ squared is $4$ square kilometers.